# Create desktop shortcut to MagicMirror

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop, lxterminal

I'm relatively new to Raspberry Pi but I have set up MagicMirror2 and got it running as it should. However, as this physical mirror is going to also be used as a streaming video screen I do not want MagicMirror to run at startup.
My solution would be to add a desktop shortcut to it, however every time I try to edit a shortcut to Terminal it ignores the working directory and command I enter.
How can I create a shortcut to at least the correct folder? Ideally I would have something that opens up MagicMirror with a double click.
My background is Microsoft environment where they cater to people without a lot of technical skills so Pi is proving a little difficult for me to master